# Multi level Multi select extended choice parameter properties file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

I want to use "Multi level Multi select" feature in "extended choice parameter" in Jenkins configuration. But my properties file is in gitlab. How can I use it?
Is there any other alternative way apart from placing my properties file in Jenkins server?

My purpose is to create a small file with list of deployment objects and control which objects to deploy and which objects not to at different levels. Could you please help.